# On a simple png file movement by changing z axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 2D simple background image and two different players on it. I can move them but when they are on the same point in the world, one of them seems to be underneath. How can I change the Z-axis of my players using the moving key?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Moving : MonoBehaviour {

    float speed = 5f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0,0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0,180);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)) {
            transform.Translate(-Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with `....on same point one of them seem bottom.`?

Comment: ı can move first character with  wasd key and second with uparrow,downmarrow,leftarow and rightarrow. For example at the middle of background 1st character seem on 2nd character. But I want them to seem if 1st character is closer the top of scene than 2nd,their graphics must be   bottom of otherone.

Comment: Are you looking for something as simple as `var p = transform.position; p.z = p.y; transform.position = p;` at the end of `Update` or something more complex?

Comment: Think like photoshop layers. If layer 2 bottom of 1st it doesnt seem fully.

Answer (score 0):

Use it as Sprites! And change the order in Layer!

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteRenderer.html

[image]

if you need to change size, just change the scale.

Comment: Good start, but how do you suggest changing `order in layer` to produce the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

Since your game is using sprite-based graphics, you can manipulate the [`sortingLayerName`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sortingLayerName.html) and [`sortingOrder`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sortingOrder.html) of the sprites to determine which one is drawn first. You can learn more about this via [sorting layer tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/sorting-layers).

If sorting layers won't work, an older and more traditional method is to move one object slightly closer to the camera. This is ideal with an orthographic camera, where the depth is irrelevant visually but does determine drawing order.